# Weird error while trying to play .mp3 sound effects in xcode?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, linker-errors

I am trying to code the simplest 'press a button an hear a sound' setup in xcode as possible, and am still managing to get some cryptic errors. Here is my code:

In .h file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

In .m file:

```
- (IBAction)beepButton:(UIButton *)sender {
       NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                   pathForResource:@"buttonBeep"
                                                   ofType:@"mp3"]];
        AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
        [click play];
    //[click release];
}
```

When I try to compile my app, I get the errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyFirstViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you added them in your frameworks.?

Comment: do you added the AVFoundation.framework in the Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a linker error. This is done after everything is compiled OK.

The problem is with the symbol `_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer`. What you do is ignore the part up through the dollar sign leaving you with `AVAudioPlayer`.

Since you are trying to use the `AVAudioPlayer` class and you import `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` you need to realize that you must include the `AVFoundation.framework` in your project.

If you look at the reference docs for `AVAudioPlayer`, you will see that the docs state it is in the `AVFoundation.framework`. This is how you know you need to add it to your project.

Comment: Very thorough, and helped me understand the cause of the error instead of just debugging this specific code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `AVFoundation.framework` to your project, because it contains the  `AVAudioPlayer` class

Answer (score 1):

have u added the AVFoundation.framework? and make sure your .mp3 file appears in "copy bundle resources"